# how to count primitive operations in a while loop in best and worst case?

Tags: pseudocode, counting, operations

I understand how to do the for loop but a while with two statements i am not sure.

```
while ( i >0 and x< A[i-1])
```

maybe break it down into two if statements?

```
if i>0
   if x<A[i-1]
```

but how do i find the best and worst case in terms of n here?

Comment: Maybe I get the question wrong, but you can't replace a loop with if-statements. They have completely different usages. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: What are `i` and `A[i-1]`? You should give us more to work with!

Comment: insert alg( A, n x)
i = n

after loop
a[i] = x
n = n+1

Answer (score 0):

> **`while ( i >0 and x< A[i-1])`**
>   "maybe break it down into two if statements?"

Yes you can do this

```
while(true) {
    if(i > 0) {
        if(x < A[i-1]) {
            // break; or continue; here, whatever your logic actually needs
        }
    }
}
```